# lower bound of a sectional curve

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

We say that a curve $ \alpha: I\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2 $ is "sectional" if $ \alpha $ is a simple closed such that $\alpha$ divides $\mathbb{S}^2$ into two regions of equal area. I'm interested in showing that
$$\inf \{L(\alpha):\alpha  \ \ sectional\}\geq 2\pi$$
where $ L(\alpha) $ is the length of $\alpha$.

I appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Using spherical coordinates (inclination $\phi$, azimuth $\theta$), the integrals for the arc length and the two areas (assuming an explicit relation $\phi=f(\theta))$ are: $\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{\sin^2\phi\ d^2\theta+d^2\phi}$, $\int_0^{2\pi}(1-\cos\phi)\ d\theta$, and $\int_0^{2\pi}(\cos\phi+1)\ d\theta$.

Comment: This is a special case of the [spherical isoperimetric inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality#The_isoperimetric_inequality_on_the_sphere).